# python Priority Queue implementation

Tags: python, priority-queue

i'm having trouble creating an insert function with the following parameters. The insert function should take in a priority queue, and an element and inserts it using the priority rules -

The priority queue will take a series of tasks and order them
based on their importance. Each task has an integer priority from 10 (highest priority) to 1
(lowest priority). If two tasks have the same priority, the order should be based on the order
they were inserted into the priority queue (earlier ﬁrst).

So, as of right now i've created the following code to initialize some of the things needed...

```
class Tasks():
    __slots__ = ('name', 'priority')

     def __init__(bval):
         bval.name = myName
         bval.priority = myPriority
         return bval

class PriorityQueue():
    __slots__ = ('queue', 'element')

     def __init__(aval):
         aval.queue = queue
         aval.element = element
         return aval
```

The code i'm trying to write is insert(element, queue): which should insert the elements using the priority queue. Similarly, myPriorty is an integer from 1 to 10.

Similarly can I do the following to insure that I create a priority from 1 to 10...

```
def __init__(bval , myPriority = 10):
      bval.priority = myPriority
      bval.pq = [[] for priority in range(bval.myPriority)]
```

so that I can replace myPriority in the insert task with bval.pq

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Style Note: aval and bval should really just be "self".

It is also unclear where the variables that you are assigning in the constructors are coming from.

Comment: I replaced them with self. @TylerCrompton I've been looking at the heap implementation since i'm now allowed to use the actual priority.queue() call.

Comment: Using `aval` and `bval` confused the heck out of me why I first saw that. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A deque (`from collections import deque`) is the python implementation of a single queue. You can add items to one end and remove them from the other. If you have a deque for each priority level, you can add to the priority level you want.

Together, it looks a bit like this:

```
from collections import deque

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self, priorities=10):
        self.subqueues = [deque() for _ in range(levels)]

    def enqueue(self, priorty, value):
        self.subqueues[priority].append(value)

    def dequeue(self):
        for queue in self.subqueues:
            try:
                return queue.popleft()
            except IndexError:
                continue
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

from Queue import PriorityQueue

http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html?highlight=priorityqueue#Queue.PriorityQueue

The lowest valued entries are retrieved first (the lowest valued entry is the one returned by sorted(list(entries))[0]). A typical pattern for entries is a tuple in the form:

(priority_number, data).

I use such a module to communicate between the UI and a background polling thread.

```
READ_LOOP = 5
LOW_PRI = 3
MED_PRI = 2
HI_PRI = 1
X_HI_PRI = 0
```

and then something like this:

```
CoreGUI.TX_queue.put((X_HI_PRI,'STOP',[]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). If you are okay with it being synchronized, I would use that.

Otherwise, you should use a heap to maintain your queue. See Python documentation with an [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) of that.

Comment: The question is asking for a different definition of a priority queue. There are only 10 priority levels, but within each level, it is a normal linear queue ordering.

Comment: @kazagistar, that is *exactly* a priority queue. The example I referenced maintains equally ranked items in the order that they are inserted, like the OP asked.

Comment: Right, but with a complexity of O(logN) for each insert and delete, which is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @kazagistar, sure, but the priority queue works. May heaven forgive me for every time I do O(log n) where I could do O(1).

Answer (score 1):

From a great book "[Modern Python Standard Library Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1788830822)" by Alessandro Molina

> Heaps are a perfect match for everything that has priorities, such as
>   a priority queue:

```
import time
import heapq

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._q = []

    def add(self, value, priority=0):
        heapq.heappush(self._q, (priority, time.time(), value))

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self._q)[-1]
```

Example:

```
>>> def f1(): print('hello')
>>> def f2(): print('world')
>>>
>>> pq = PriorityQueue()
>>> pq.add(f2, priority=1)
>>> pq.add(f1, priority=0)
>>> pq.pop()()
hello
>>> pq.pop()()
world
```